# Não consigo fazer insert com array

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho um form com os seguintes elementos:

```
 <form name="dadosLocacao" action="registra_locacao.php" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="filme">Filme</label>
        <br>
        <select class="selectpicker lg" multiple data-live-search="true" name="select_filmes[]">
           <option>Selecione o Filme</option>
           <?php

           $result_filmes = "SELECT * FROM filmes";
           $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result_filmes);
           while($row_filmes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
              ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row_filmes['id']; ?>"> <?php echo utf8_encode($row_filmes['descricao']); ?>
              </option>

              <?php
           }

           ?>
        </select>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
           <label for="datalocacao">Data da Locação</label>
           <input type="date" class="form-control" name="datalocacao" id="datalocacao">
     </div>


        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="filme">Cliente</label>
        <br>
        <select class="selectpicker lg" data-live-search="true" name="select_clientes">
           <option>Selecione o Cliente</option>
           <?php

           $result_filmes = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
           $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result_filmes);
           while($row_cliente = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
              ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row_cliente['id']; ?>"> <?php echo utf8_encode($row_cliente['nome']); ?>
              </option>

              <?php
           }

           ?>
        </select>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="observacao">Observação</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="observacao" name="observacao"></textarea>
     </div>

     <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="inserir">
           <div class="form-group">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Cadastrar</button>
           </div>
   </div>
   </form>
```

Meu arquivo registra_locacao.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['acao'])){
    if($_POST['acao'] == "inserir"){
    insereLocacao();
    }
    if($_POST['acao'] == "alterar"){
        alteraLocacao();
    }
    if($_POST['acao'] == "excluir"){
        excluiLocacao();
    }
}

function abrirBanco(){
    $conexao = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "locadora");
    return $conexao;
}

function insereLocacao(){
     $select_filmes = $_POST["select_filmes"];
     $datalocacao = $_POST["datalocacao"];
     $select_clientes = $_POST["select_clientes"];
     $observacao = $_POST["observacao"];

    $dados = count($select_filmes);
    $banco = abrirBanco();

    for($i=0; $i<$dados;$i++){
        $filmeindice = $select_filmes[$i];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO locacao(id_locacao,id_cliente,id_filme,data_locacao,observacao) VALUES (NULL,'$select_clientes', '$filmeindice', '$datalocacao', '$observacao' ";

    $banco->query($sql);

}
    $banco->close();

    header('Location: home.php');
}
```

não estou conseguindo inserir registros, quando eu faço a query no banco funciona normalmente, mas através do php não consigo. alguém sabe onde estou errando?

Answer (score 0):

A sua *query* está inválida.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO locacao (
    id_locacao,
    id_cliente,
    id_filme,
    data_locacao,
    observacao) 
VALUES (
    NULL,
    '$select_clientes',
    '$filmeindice',
    '$datalocacao',
    '$observacao' ";
```

Está faltando fechar o parêntese de `VALUES`.

O correto é:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO locacao (
    id_locacao,
    id_cliente,
    id_filme,
    data_locacao,
    observacao) 
VALUES (
    NULL,
    '$select_clientes',
    '$filmeindice',
    '$datalocacao',
    '$observacao');";
```

Quando você trabalha com `MySQLi`, você pode utilizar a função `mysqli_error` ou utilizar a propriedade `error`, por exemplo:

```
/* Orientado à Objetos */
if (!$mysqli->query($sql)) {
    die("Houve um erro: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}

/* Estilo procedural */
if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    die("Houve um erro: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Dessa forma você consegue visualizar o erro mais rapidamente.

Comment: Boa dica Valdeir, eu só acrescentaria considerar a usar PDO, pois esse código assim está totalmente vulnerável a injections

Comment: @Marcelo `PDO` não vai tornar a essa *query* segura e o `MySQLi` é tão seguro quanto (e mais rápido também). Mas foi bem observado, ela precisa melhorar quanto a segurança (caso ela não esteja filtrando os dados antes de executar a *query*).